# Rails ActiveRecord Associations that include "owner" role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I’m creating a chore tracker app as my first Rails project and I’m wondering if the associations I've created make sense or could be improved.  Here are the details of the app:

- A user makes a chore list and becomes the “owner”(i.e. “admin”) of
  that list.
- The owner can create/edit chores for the list.  They can also “approve" other users to complete tasks on the list.  These users can ONLY complete tasks.
- The owner, along with the usual admin abilities, can also complete
  tasks on a list that they own.
- Owners can own multiple lists. Users can be approved to complete
  tasks on multiple lists.

And here are the relationships I’ve roughed out that I’m looking for feedback on:

**(Model)User**

- has_many :lists
- has_many :owners, class_name: “List”, foreign_key: “list_id"
- has_many :chores, through: :lists

**(Model)List**

- has_many :users
- has_many :chores
- belongs_to :owner, class_name: “User”, foreign_key: “owner_id"

**(Model)User_List**

- belongs_to :user
- belongs_to :list

**(Model)Chore**

- belongs_to :list
- has_many :users, through: :lists

Any red flags?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
# user.rb
class User
  has_many :lists_users
  has_many :lists, through: :lists_users
  has_many :chores, through :lists
end

# list.rb
class List
  has_many :lists_users
  has_many :users, through: :lists_users
  has_many :chores
end

# lists_user.rb
class ListsUser
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :list

  # field (Representational, add it in database)
  :user_role
    - member (can view)
    - collaborator (can mark complete)
    - owner (can do everything)
end

# chore.rb
class Chore
  belongs_to :list
end
```

NOTE: I changed the association model to `ListsUser` as per rails naming conventions.

Please let me know if i missed something.

Comment: This makes sense.  Just so I can make sure I'm understanding, because a user can belong to many lists, but only one role for that list, I can add the role column to ListUsers instead of User?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why i added role column in ListUsers.